# Labelling figures in the tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman, tikz-feynman

Consider the following piece of code, which uses the *tikz-feynman* package:

```
\usepackage{tikz-feynman, contour}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
    \begin{feynman}
        \diagram [vertical'=a to b] {
            {   [edges={draw=none}]
                a -- b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
                -- c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
                -- d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
                -- a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
            },
            {   [edges={photon}]
                a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
                b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
                d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
                c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
            },
        };
        \diagram* {
            (c) -- [fermion] (b)
                -- [fermion] (d)
                -- [fermion] (a)
                -- (c),
        };
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \feynmandiagram[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, vertical'=a to b,] {
        {   [edges={fermion}]
            a -- b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
            -- c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
            -- d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
            -- a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
        },
        {   [edges={photon}]
            a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
            b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
            d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
            c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
        },
    };
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
    \begin{feynman}
        \diagram [vertical'=a to b] {
            {   [edges={draw=none}]
                a -- b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
                -- c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
                -- d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
                -- a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
            },
            {   [edges={photon}]
                a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
                b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
                d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
                c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
            },
        };
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [anti fermion] (b)
                -- [anti fermion] (d)
                -- [anti fermion] (c)
                -- (a),
        };
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

This piece of code draws the following figure:

[image]

I would like to label each figure. I do not want a caption, but just a label beneath each diagram. The label should say Diagram I, Diagram II, Diagram III.

How do I implement this into my code?

Comment: First lines on your code are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get the expected diagram, but it doesn't matter to my answer: Use a  `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman, contour}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
    \begin{feynman}
        \diagram [vertical'=a to b] {
            {   [edges={draw=none}]
                a -- b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
                -- c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
                -- d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
                -- a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
            },
            {   [edges={photon}]
                a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
                b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
                d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
                c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
            },
        };
        \diagram* {
            (c) -- [fermion] (b)
                -- [fermion] (d)
                -- [fermion] (a)
                -- (c),
        };
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \feynmandiagram[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, vertical'=a to b,] {
        {   [edges={fermion}]
            a -- b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
            -- c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
            -- d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
            -- a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
        },
        {   [edges={photon}]
            a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
            b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
            d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
            c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
        },
    };
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
    \begin{feynman}
        \diagram [vertical'=a to b] {
            {   [edges={draw=none}]
                a -- b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
                -- c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
                -- d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
                -- a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
            },
            {   [edges={photon}]
                a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
                b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
                d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
                c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
            },
        };
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [anti fermion] (b)
                -- [anti fermion] (d)
                -- [anti fermion] (c)
                -- (a),
        };
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    Diagram I & Diagram II & Diagram III
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```